# How to resolve mkdir : missing operand error in linux?

Tags: command-line, bash, mkdir

I am very new to the linux , i am trying to make a directories  from the files which is present in the current working directory, one directory is created but another one is not creating it's throwing an error like
`mkdir: missing operand`

```
for files in *.txt
do
folderName= echo $files | awk -F. '{print $1}';
mkdir $folderName;
done
```

Comment: Which one is not working? Better use $(basename $file .txt) to retrieve the base name of the file.

Comment: why do you assume $folderName has a value? :)

Comment: Use string manipulation instead: `mkdir "${file%.*}"`, then you can skip this folderName thing altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the output of a command as a new variable, put the command between `$()`. Like this:

`folderName=$(echo $files|awk -F. '{print $1} ';)`

To see what you're doing, add another `echo` command to confirm that the folder name has been correctly constructed:

`echo $folderName`

before you do the `mkdir`.